# Can a second-order busy beaver function/turing machine be programmed?

Tags: busy-beaver

I have seen a computer program at https://github.com/pkrumins/busy-beaver/blob/master/busy-beaver.py that computes Busy Beaver numbers (well, pretends to). It has busy beaver numbers up to 4, and I am wondering if it is possible (reasonably) for a programmer to add a second-order, n-state, 2-symbol Turing machine.